# list.remove method is not working

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I'm a beginner, and I have this code that is part of a bigger guess the number game (where the computer guesses), and my legal function is not deleting any part of the list. I also print the list after the function has been called later on, and it just prints the whole list. Here's my code:

```
legal_guesses = []
for number in range(1,101):
    legal_guesses.append(number)

def legal(thing):

    for number in range(min(legal_guesses), max(legal_guesses)):
        if thing == "higher":
            if number <= the_guess:
                print(number)
                legal_guesses.remove(number)
```

Comment: Where is your `legal` function being called?

Comment: Are you sure that `number` is smaller than or equal to `the_guess`?

Comment: the error isn't necessarily in the code you just posted

Comment: Maybe `thing != "higher"`?

Comment: http://ideone.com/wmeK8s Your code works fine and removes from the list

Answer (score 0):

few points:

- modifying a `list` that you are iterating on is a bad idea in general.
- you can use the `set()` datastructure which will work just as well if not better.